# Branching Factor and Overhead

Tags: artificial-intelligence

The branching factor is the number of successors generated by a given node. The effective branching factor is the number of successors generated by a "typical" node for a given search problem.And the depth is The height of a node Y is the number of edges on the longest downward simple path from Y to a leaf. The height of a tree is defined as the height of its root node. Note that a simple path is a path without repeat vertices. The height of a tree is equal to the maximum depth of a tree.I want to know what is effect on overhead by increasing or decreasing the branching factor and depth?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look at the help center, in particular [how to ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What part are you stuck on? What have you tried?

Comment: No you also need to define the algorithm you are intending to use... and to define the overhead in comparison to what

Comment: I am using Intensive Deepning.